# Jquery-steps nested wizard

Tags: jquery-steps

I try creating nested wizard with jQuery Steps plugin. On the official site written

> Multiple wizards
>       Have multiple wizards on one page or even have nested wizards like you want.

site -> http://www.jquery-steps.com/GettingStarted

But when I try this, I'm getting confused. Before step with nested wizard, all fine. But after this step slides content is not displayed.

[Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jkt6/)

All code (including Css) taken from the demo example of project. [From here](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/tree/master/demo)

I just added next code snippets

```
$("#wizard_embedded").steps();

<div id="wizard_embedded">
    <h1>Embedded Wizzard Step 1</h1>
    <div>Embedded Wizzard Content 1</div>
    <h1>Embedded Wizzard Step 2</h1>
    <div>Embedded Wizzard Content 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested it and found some small issues on js and css site. Worked once a while ago. Seems to be a regression bug. I will fix it. Would be nice if you could post a bug on [github](http://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/issues) with a meaningful title and describtion.

Comment: i recently wrote to [this issue](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/issues/23). create a new one?